# Can Debezium be used to commit changes directly to another DB?

Tags: debezium

I am interested if there's a way to use Debezium to CDC on one DB and commit every change to another DB (instead of committing and consuming Kafka in the middle). I have seen there's a way to write changes to a file but couldn't find anything about writing to a DB. In a sense, the question is whether I can combine source-connector and sink-connector configuration for one Debezium..?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use Debezium as a CDC tool, please refer to my project on [github](https://github.com/dursunkoc/debezium-samples), there I copy data changes from mysql to postgresql, and on another [project](https://github.com/dursunkoc/debezium_w_ora) I copy changes from an oracle database to another oracle database.

Comment: If I understand correctly, your example works with Kafka and it doesn't answer my question which was about Debezium reading from one DB and writing directly to another DB.

Comment: debezium without kafka does not seem to be a good option, afaik it may not be possible.